# Android Manifest error when trying to build project

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, build, manifest

I have been trying to build my project for sometime now and each time i try to  build it i get the error and a file comes up that i have no idea about (debug/AndroidManifest.xml)
I have invalidated caches and restarted several times to no avail.
i have cleaned the project several times and still getting the same. I even went further to toggle my build variants between release and debug. Still no solution

see the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

aapt error unexcepted element.
it means  in the wrong level.
check or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent filter is in wrong place. Where it shows that you commented out the activity which was supposed to use the intent. remove the line and build again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).